# Logstash condition to check if message contains any of from list of string

Tags: conditional-statements, logstash

I have a javastack trace in message field and an array field having list of string like ["NullPointer", "TimeOutException"].

I want a conditional check on message field such that it checks if message contains any of from list of string.

Any idea how to get this?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a hack, but check out the translate{} filter.   You could define your fields to translate to "1" (true, etc), with a default of "0".  Then check that value to determine if it was in the set.

EDIT: for those who don't like to fish:

```
filter {
  translate {
    field => myInputField
    dictionary => [
      "NullPointer",      1,
      "TimeOutException", 1
    ]
    fallback => 0
    destination => myOutputField
  }

  if [myOutputField] == "1" {
      # it contained one of the items in the dictionary
      ...
  }
  else {
      # it did not contain one of the items in the dictionary
      ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please give some example?